# Python CGI: Persistence with Session Keys

Tags: python, cgi

Total novice here!

I am trying to create a simple web interface for SUSE Manager using it's API. The issue I am encountering isn't really with SUSE Manager, but with CGI. Right now, I simply want to accomplish two things at the moment:

1) Log in screen where the user enters in their username and password for SUSE Manager.

2) After logging in, the user has multiple links for running different API calls for the application.

In the index.html file, I have the forms to log in and submit the username and password values to "auth.py".

```
<html>
<title>Login</title>a/
<body> 
<b>SuSE Manager Tools</b><br /><br />
<form action="/cgi-bin/auth.py" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The "auth.py" then authenticates with the server and generates a session key. This key will be used for all authentication going forward when running API procedure calls.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import cgi, cgitb, xmlrpclib, os
print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
MANAGER_URL = "http://susemanager"
MANAGER_LOGIN = form.getvalue('username')
MANAGER_PASSWORD = form.getvalue('password')
client = xmlrpclib.Server(MANAGER_URL, verbose=0)
key = client.auth.login(MANAGER_LOGIN, MANAGER_PASSWORD)
```

Now I have a bunch of individual '.py' files that run these procedure calls. I would at this point present the user with several links to run specified procedures. My question is, what is a good method of passing these session keys to the .py files so that they can authenticate against the server?

Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong? Perhaps CGI isn't the answer. There seems to be a lot of hub bub around CGI not being the best choice these days and that it has become outdated. Maybe I should be looking into WSGI or do you think for something so simple, CGI remains the better option?

Thanks folks.

Comment: Yes, use a simple wsgi framework like Flask; there are various session libraries available.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll take a look at Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Flask and the built-in 'session' module, I was able to get this done like so:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, redirect, url_for
import xmlrpclib
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            session['user'] = request.form['username']
            session['passwd'] = request.form['password']
            return redirect(url_for('menu'))        
    return render_template('login.html')
@app.route('/menu/')
def menu():
    user = session.get('user', None)
    passwd = session.get('passwd', None)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please don't store sensitive information in session as that may make them available in cookies and requests.